# State Variables in Storage: "lower-order aligned" What does this sentence in the docs mean?

Tags: solidity

I am new to solidity and am trying to understand this sentence in the docs covering state variables in storage.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage

A bullet item says the following:

> The first item in a storage slot is stored lower-order aligned.

What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first item in a storage slot is stored lower-order aligned.

**It means the data within the slot is ordered as big endian.**

This information is useful if you are going to use bitwise operators, `assembly` functions or advanced type casting.

---

If you're more interested in this topic, [this article](https://jeancvllr.medium.com/solidity-tutorial-all-about-bytes-9d88fdb22676) explains the endianness in Solidity in more depth.

Comment: Thank you! Just happens that I am reading about this now. Thanks for the help.